# Why isn't Miles surprised by Andi's attendance?

Tags: plot-explanation, glass-onion-a-knives-out-mystery

Glass Onion was sure very fun and delightful to watch but the plot doesn't make much sense to me for reasons I'll explain below. I appreciate someone clearing up my confusions.

So Miles knew that he himself had killed Andi earlier. This brings up a number of questions.

1. Why did he invite her to begin with? No one expected him to do so anyway. And by inviting her he actually enabled her sister to come and wreck everything.

   Miles wasn't as surprised or as unsettled by Andi's appearance as one would expect him to be. We see him look at her very surprised early on. But they don't really interact after that. He should be very shocked to see a dead person alive and well after all but he doesn't seem to care and his plans don't seem to have changed.

   If Duke was able to instantly deduce that Miles had killed Andi by just seeing the news, he should have suspected that earlier as well, yet we don't see any sign of that in the movie. All he does is show the news to Miles and hint at the Alpha News deal and then happily starts drinking which is unexpected given that he now knows that there is a ghost among them.

One explanation could be that both Miles and Duke guessed that Andi's twin sister has come instead, but again that should bring up more questions and confusion for them which it doesn't. The rest of the "shitheads" don't even remember that Andi has a twin sister so one expects Miles and Duke to be no different.

I came out of the the movie theater very confused after watching this. I'll rewatch it on Netflix when it's available to see if I have missed anything, but reading the Wikipedia synopsis didn't shed much light on this either, so I think it's a plot problem.

Comment: To begin with, he shouldn't have invited her and then the whole thing didn't need to happen and he the rest of the gang could just settle things on their own. I just fail to see any rationale behind the whole premise.

Comment: The invitation was sent before, it tooks weeks to create those special customized puzzles, so he couldn't cancel it without sounding suspicious

Answer (score 11):

Blanc mentions that Andi's murder was cowardly because the murderer didn't have to actually watch her die. With the news of her death suppressed, Miles probably assumed that he had failed to kill Andi.

It's important to remember that Miles's two key personality traits are that he's not smart, but he's got a confidence that can only come from extreme wealth. He thinks he's untouchable. Even if an unmurdered Andi shows up and knew what he had done, Miles thinks his status and wealth would protect him.

Miles also has fairly muted and/or controlled responses to other surprises, like when Helen comes down the stairs with the red envelope and when Duke shows him the news report about Andi. It's likely that this is part of the secret to his success, as it allows him to fake competence and pivot to ride surprise trends for his advantage when they should sink him.

The box was probably finished and in transit before the murder. Miles might have had it sent to add insult to injury, but as the movie portrays he doesn't really think ahead, even maliciously. It's more likely that, as a man who is never told 'no' even by all of the experts he employs at his companies, he just doesn't understand that Andi wouldn't want to be his friend anymore. Of course, everyone wants to be his friend, he's rich.

Duke isn't the brightest bulb either so it's tough to say just how much he knew about Miles's involvement in Andi's death, but he's self-absorbed enough to just be interested in what he could get out of the situation.

Comment: In support of the third paragraph, after he burns the napkin, Miles asks if anyone saw anything clearly. When they remain silent and he knows he's safe, he lightens up again. This light mood continues when Helen starts smashing the glass sculptures, but more interestingly also continues when the others start smashing the glass sculptures. Even though this hints that his friends/underlings are starting to turn on him, **Miles remains arrogantly confident that he's safe**. It takes them explicitly turning on him and proclaiming what they "saw" for Miles to finally change his tune.

Answer (score 3):

He sent out the packages before he murdered Cassandra. The Disruptors received the boxes on May 13th (it says in the beginning of the movie) and Andi sent the email to everyone on May 11th (it says so on the email), two days before the gang got the invitations. It's stated that one day after the email was sent, Miles went to Andi's house on May 12th

He didn't intend to kill her but that changed two days prior to getting the box. Miles said himself that the puzzle guys who designed the boxes barely got it finished on time to deliver.

My point being, I highly doubt that he sent and got the packages delivered to everyone ONE DAY AFTER the murder.

The trial happened a few months before the events of the movie, so she would regularly go to Miles' annual parties it seems, and people thought she wouldn't this time since the trial costed her everything.

He originally wanted her to come (before getting the email and changing his mind) in order to gloat and remind her how her former friends chose him over her. He wanted to announce the launch of the energy source Klear and shove his success in her face and had no idea she had the envelope until later.

By the time he got the email, the packages were already shipped. But Miles thought it wouldn't matter considering everyone else would simply assume that she didn't accept the invitation, which makes sense after what happened.

Lionel actually said that the strange part wasn't inviting her, it's that she accepted the invitation at all. This indicates that Miles would invite her every year, but that she wouldn't have come this time due to Miles and her former friends betraying her.

It takes a while to deliver packages in the US. I mean the average shipping time for packages from Greece (where the Glass Onion is) to the USA is 15-17 days.

The day of the party is May 22nd (that's the date on the article on Andi's death, which Duke received on his phone shortly before his murder) and so the gang arrived over a week later to the party.

He doesn't look surprised when she comes because he doesn't want to look suspicious in front of everyone. He has to wait for an opportune moment, but he must attend to the party, while watching the other guests and making sure things seem okay. Plus there's also Duke who saw him go to Andi's house. Although Duke didn't know Andi was dead until later, he still could alert the group that he was there too.

Why would Duke think that Andi was killed before he saw the article? No one automatically assumes one murdered someone. Similar to Andi, no one thought Miles was capable of murder. For all Duke knows, Miles faced a similar situation, being that she didn't answer and Miles left after waiting a while for Andi to open the door.

Miles thinks that since Duke saw him leave, it would look suspicious considering he arrived WAY before everyone else, and Andi doesn't answer the door for anyone else that arrives. At least that's from MILES'S perspective, not Duke's, which I explained prior, along with the fact that he's worried about Andi more and distracted due to the damage she can do to his career.

When he does receive the news, of course he's happy. The one person that could ruin Miles (and by extension the rest of the group) is gone, and he thought he got what he wanted in exchange for his silence, since he still hates Miles (just like Andi, he could ruin his career and he hates holding on to Miles)

Comment: Remember that Miles did not see Andi die, he only presumes she is dead. Earlier in the film there is a line that says, because of the method of dispatch, the killer would not even have to "see her die". So his reaction at seeing her arrive could also be "ah, so it didn't work.."

Comment: It's unlikely that Bron's puzzle guy built the puzzles in Greece. They were probably built in and shipped from the U.S.

Answer (score 2):

Although We don't know the full and detailed timeline, we know that Andi is part of the "disruptors" and Miles had order the customized puzzles weeks ago for all its members, presumably before Miles' "visit" to Andi house.

How could he cancel or change the order without sounding suspicious? How can he say it can't be Andi?

Also leaving loose ends as Andi puzzle is consistent with Miles reckless (not to say stupid) behavior, for example forgetting  to get rid of Andi's incriminating letter.

Miles seems calm because he thinks no one can outsmart him and likes to do as minimal work as possible (with his self sustaining island).

Comment: That makes sense, however the court battle was months earlier that would have given him enough pretext to avoid inviting her?

Comment: @Paghillect maybe, but all the team members hate him, so why should  he invite anyone?

Comment: He didn't "forget to get rid of Andi's incriminating letter."

Comment: @BCdotWEB he didn't immediately burnt it and let the detective find it

Comment: That doesn't mean he "forgot" to do this.